# Banderas no cambian al tener enlace

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo este menu desplegable de banderas que cambian de posicion al hacer clic sobre la otra, mi problema es el siguiente, las banderas solo cambian si les quitan el enlace con "#", en cambio si se usa algun enlace, se sigue manteniendo la misma la primera bandera, les dejo enlace para que puedan bajar el archivo y probar desde sus pc : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nHpDtt_pCtxlD47txSQaUvVv_K5uX7tv .Necesito que la bandera principal, en este caso inglaterra, cambie cuando se clicke en las demas banderas que tienen enlace. Muchas gracias por la atención.

```js
      let bandera = document.querySelector("#principal")
      let banderas = document.querySelector(".contenedor-banderas")
      
      banderas.addEventListener("click", (evento) => {
        bandera.setAttribute("src", evento.target.src)
      })
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
   
   * {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
   }
   
   #header {
    margin:auto;
    width:500px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
   
   ul, ol {
    list-style:none;
   }
   
   .nav > li {
    float:left;
   }
   
   .nav li a {
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px 12px;
    display:block;
   }
   
   .nav li a:hover {
    background-color:#434343;
   }
   
   .nav li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    min-width:50px;
   }
   
   .nav li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
   }
   
   .nav li ul li {
    position:relative;
   }
   
   .nav li ul li ul {
    right:-140px;
    top:0px;
   }
   
  </style>
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Menu Desplegable</title>
  <link href='https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="header">
    <ul class="nav">
   
    
    <li><a href="#"><img id="principal" src="https://i.imgur.com/JfcgMq3.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/><i class="fas fa-caret-down" style="font-size:20px; color:#ffffff;"></i></a>
        <ul class="contenedor-banderas">
      <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/29.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/skxVw7A.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a></a></li>
      <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/29.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/iZzY1wO.png"width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/29.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/fVxPzVF.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/USER/Desktop/29.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Qaf0696.png" width="28" height="28" style="left:-5px;"/></a>
       
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    
    </li>
   
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Talvez tiene que ver con que tienes 4 enlaces iguales?....

Comment: Esos enlaces lo pongo como ejemplo, ya que estoy probando desde un archivo .html  Si quito los enlaces a cada uno de los <li> funciona normal, estoy publicando este tema, ya que intento hacer un menu desplegable que sea tipo traductor, tengo otro archivo .html, con el mismo codigo y distintos enlaces, cada una de las banderas tiene un enlace especifico de mi pagina traducida. Ejemplo la pagina se traduce del ingles al aleman pero no cambia la bandera, sigue estando la misma (la de inglaterra) y eso quiero solucionar que al momento de traducir la pagina cambie la bandera segun el idioma elegido